# How to pass 'nil' as a value of parameter through form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

feed_entries table contains `last_clicked_on:datetime` attribute, it is nil by default. I just want to pass 'nil' as a value of last_clicked_on.But the below code is not working.

```
<%= form_for @search do |f|%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :last_clicked_on, value: 'nil' %>
    <%= f.submit "History" %>
<% end %>
```

Please help someone to resolve this issue.

Comment: If it is `nil` by default, why do you need to pass `nil` with the params?

Comment: I am using the metasearch gem,And in controller--def index
    @search = FeedEntry.search(params[:search])
  end -- so by passing nil as a value of params[:search]. I can able to fetch nil value data.